# Line alignment RSyntaxTextArea and RTextScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, line, rsyntaxtextarea

In my code I'm using RSyntaxTextArea and RTextScrollPane but the line numbers of the RTextScrollPane are not perfectly aligned with the lines of the RSyntaxTextArea.

Here is my code :

```
RSyntaxTextArea tabTextArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
tabTextArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
tabTextArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
tabTextArea.setAntiAliasingEnabled(true);

RTextScrollPane tabScrollPane = new RTextScrollPane(tabTextArea);
tabScrollPane.setLineNumbersEnabled(true);
tabScrollPane.getGutter().setSpacingBetweenLineNumbersAndFoldIndicator(10);
```

I've also changed the font in another part of the code, here are the parts where I made these :

For the RTextScrollPane (fontText is "OCR A Extended") :

```
((RTextScrollPane) (((SwingNode) tab.getContent()).getContent())).getGutter().setLineNumberFont(new Font(fontText, Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

For the RSyntaxTextArea (OCR_FONT_FAMILY is same as fontText) :

```
rSyntaxTextArea.setFont(new Font(OCR_FONT_FAMILY, Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

It's the same font and same size but it's not aligned. Can someone help me ?
And an important important information is that if I do not set theses font it's perfectly aligned.

Thanks !

Comment: Why is this marked JavaFX?  [RSyntaxTextArea](https://bobbylight.github.io/RSyntaxTextArea/) is a Swing control.